# Uniformity of true random numbers

Tags: random-generation, uniform-distribution, randomness

Are numbers generated by True (hardware) Random Number Generators (TRNGs) more uniform than numbers from a Pseudo Random Number Generator (PRNG)? I understand that there are not much (analytical/numerical) information of TRNGs compared with PRNGs. What are the main users of TRNGs other than in gaming and cryptography?

Comment: Uniformity is unrelated to randomness. A TRNG could create an exponentially distributed variable.

Comment: This provider of a TRNG gives some explanation of its uses https://www.random.org/

Comment: @Hugh : I have used (unprocessed) random numbers from random.org and they seem to be uniformly distributed. Their primary clients appear to be from the gaming industry.

Comment: Uniformity is usually not an issue.  In fact, most (if not all) PRNGs are constructed to be *perfectly* uniform over sufficiently long sequences (their periods).  The concerns about PRNGs are associated with lack of independence.

Comment: I don't see why this would be considered off topic here. Understanding randomness, independence, and uniformity are clearly within our mandate. We have a `[random-generation]` tag, & questions about the generation of random &/or pseudo-random variates have traditionally been considered on topic here. I'm voting to leave open.

Comment: @whuber, why not develop that into an answer? (This field is a bit esoteric & outside my expertise, but, w/ deference, I do wonder if it is a completely correct answer, however. My reasoning is that it seems to me a distribution cannot be perfectly uniform if there are gaps in the number line, as the probability of drawing a realization would be 0 w/i those gaps. Moreover, if a PRNG's period is finite, it seems to me there must be gaps, although they may be inconsequentially small. I am not sure if that would be equally true of a TRNG, & thus wonder if TRNGs could be considered more uniform.)